Does PuTTY support Web Sockets?
Normally I use SSH via PuTTY to access my cloud servers.  My cloud provider offers a serial console as a backup, for when SSH is not working.  They only provide instructions for how to use it from Linux.  I use Windows on my laptop.  Can I use PuTTY to access my server via a URL like wss://dal-cell2.hostwinds.net:6083?token=e6ac3f47-05fff9212-cfc3-e99252567d1f (token randomized)?

Maybe if you shared those Linux instructions, we could offer an equivalent solution for Windows.

It's basically run http://repo.hostwinds.net/repos/tools/serial_console.py.  I can, but I'd rather not.

You can get Python from Microsoft Store and have this running unmodified in a minute. Why, more specifically, not?

Because I normally use PuTTY for accessing servers.  I was hoping this Web Sockets thing was just some terminology I'd not heard before and was supported by PuTTY but labeled in some esoteric way.  It does all my logging, has all my keys, etc.  I really like to keep a log of everything I do to a server, that I can easily search & find later.  This type of CYA has saved me many times in the past.  I'm also not a big fan of running oddball Python scripts.  That script could be compromised in so many different ways.

At just under 150 lines, this script is very easy to audit. It also has all the required information to write your own client, if you want.

Looks like I was wrong.  I can't run it.  It requires termios, which doesn't appear to exist on Windows.

I overlooked that, sorry. I’m not a regular Python user. Looks like running this directly on Windows would be hard, then. WSL could still be an option.

WebSockets are somewhat like TCP. They transport data. An application needs to define a protocol on top, to make sense of the data.
That protocol would not be SSH and also not be Telnet.
So, no, PuTTY does not support that.

There is a noVNC web app running at https://dal-cell2.hostwinds.net:6080/. Pretty sure you could make use of that fact somehow, using any modern browser from any device.

Thank you.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get paste to work in noVNC.
